Decrease the entangled state space
I have a circuit containing two entangled qubits in a 4D vector $\begin{bmatrix} A \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ B \end{bmatrix}$,

Is there a way to encode the amplitudes $A$ and $B$ into a single qubit?
I want to decrease the state space from $\begin{bmatrix} A \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ B \end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}$ by encoding the $\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}$ information into one qubit.

You mean you want to create something that is actually just the first qubit just before you do the controlled-not?

@DaftWullie that's correct for my MWE.  The actual problem that I'm trying to solve is more complicated than the rotations/CNOT, but it basically has an entangled [A 0 0 B] state like in the MWE.

You could keep working with the full state and apply operations just to the top qubit. The probability amplitudes will evolve as if you only had one qubit. Then, at the end of your circuit, discard the bottom qubit and perform measurements only on the top qubit. The statistics will be the same as if you only had the top qubit all along.
Alternatively, apply another CX gate to disentangle the qubits:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} A \\ 0 \\ 0 \\B \end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{CX} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix},$$
and disregard the bottom qubit.
